# KNN: "no missing values are allow" -> I do not have missing values

Tags: r, testing, knn, training-data

I am in a group project for a class and one of the people in my group ran the normalization, as well as creating the test/train sets so that we all have the same sets to work from (we're all utilizing different algorithms). I am assigned with running the KNN algorithm.

We had multiple columns with NA's so those columns were omitted (`<-NULL`). When attempting to run the KNN I keep getting the error of

```r
Error in knn(train = trainsetne, test = testsetne, cl = ne_train_target,  :
  no missing values are allowed
```

I ran `which(is.na(dataset$col))` and found:

```r
which(is.na(testsetne$median_days_on_market))
# [1] 8038 8097 8098 8100 8293 8304
```

When I look through the dataset those cells do not have missing data.

I am wondering if I may get some help with how to either find and fix the "No missing values" or to find a work around (if any).

I am sorry if I am missing something simple. Any help is appreciated.

I have listed the code that we have below:

```r
ne$pending_ratio_yy <- ne$total_listing_count_yy <- ne$average_listing_price_yy <- ne$median_square_feet_yy <- ne$median_listing_price_per_square_feet_yy <- ne$pending_listing_count_yy <- ne$price_reduced_count_yy <- ne$median_days_on_market_yy <- ne$new_listing_count_yy <- ne$price_increased_count_yy <- ne$active_listing_count_yy <- ne$median_listing_price_yy <- ne$flag <- NULL

ne$pending_ratio_mm <- ne$total_listing_count_mm <- ne$average_listing_price_mm <- ne$median_square_feet_mm <- ne$median_listing_price_per_square_feet_mm <- ne$pending_listing_count_mm  <- ne$price_reduced_count_mm <- ne$price_increased_count_mm <- ne$new_listing_count_mm <- ne$median_days_on_market_mm <- ne$active_listing_count_mm <- ne$median_listing_price_mm <- NULL

ne$factor_month_date <- as.factor(ne$month_date_yyyymm)
ne$factor_median_days_on_market <- as.factor(ne$median_days_on_market)

train20ne= sample(1:20893, 4179)

trainsetne=ne[train20ne,1:10]
testsetne=ne[-train20ne,1:10]

#This is where I start to come in

ne_train_target <- ne[train20ne, 3]
ne_test_target <- ne[-train20ne, 3]

predict_1 <- knn(train = trainsetne, test = testsetne, cl=ne_train_target, k=145)
# Error in knn(train = trainsetne, test = testsetne, cl = ne_train_target,  : 
#  no missing values are allowed
```

Comment: Since we don't have your data, it's all speculation. Often when I'm in a similar situation where `is.na` reports missingness but I look at the data and cannot see the `NA` on the console, it's because of a typo on my part, exacerbated when I have an environment filled with previously-created temp variables. If you try `testsetne$median_days_on_market[c(8038,8097,8098,8100,8293,8304)]` immediately after your `which(is.na(...))` call, you're saying that you see all values, no `NA`s?

Comment: (Side note: code-fences include three backticks *plus* a language indicator, such as `lang-r`, and the code fence starts and stops must be on their own lines. I've edited your code to reflect that, feel free to [edit] it and see how I rearranged things accordingly. I also removed R code for which there was no output and otherwise not meaningful here, such as `str(...)` and `sqrt(...)`, mostly so that the code in your question does not need to scroll. If you disagree, feel free to rollback, my apologies. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help might be useful for full explanation of SO markdown)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much for the help with the code. I agree, it looks much better. I will be looking into the link shortly. I did run the ```testsetne$median_days_on_market[c(8038,8097,8098,8100,8293,8304)]``` Immediately after and it gave me ```> testsetne$median_days_on_market[c(8038,8097,8098,8100,8293,8304)]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA```

Comment: Okay. You said *"When I look through the dataset those cells do not have missing data"*, but that indicates that those values are truly missing (R's `NA` means "missing", "non-specific", "not-available", "not-applicable", or "could-be-anything" in a sense). Did it behave differently the last time you tested for missing values?

Comment: It did not. Same output. I physically scrolled through the dataset too, to see if that point 8038 was not valid and there is a number in the cell. Same with the following 5 points.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. You said *"do not have missing data"* but that clearly shows that there is missing data in that column on those rows. Perhaps you tested on one frame but "looked" at another?

Comment: I suppose I could be. I ran ```View(testsetne)``` and went to row 8038 traced over to the correct column and the number 58 is in the cell. Unless I am doing this part wrong. I appreciate your help and patience, I am a super novice with this (as you can probably tell)

Comment: Are you going to *row* 8038 or are you going to `row.names` 8038? The two are not always the same.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I was going directly to the row. I did find the 6 data points. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad I could help!